# Changing a name for a sick person

Tags: names, minhag, choleh-sick, halacha

Sometimes people add a name for a sick person. Can you just change it to an entirely different name? I know of a case where they kept the first name and changed the second name - originally the name was Menachem Mendel and they changed it to Menachem Chaim. I do not know if a Rabbi was asked and I am curious if there is any source for doing so.

Comment: [The answer](http://web.archive.org/web/20120314190000/http://www.tzemachdovid.org/thepracticaltorah/lechlecha.shtml)

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, that is how the *minhag* began. The practice of changing one's name to an entirely new and unrelated name is attested in many places relevant to *gitin* because of the precision in names necessary there. (citation needed)

Incidentally, it seems that the *minhag* was drawing upon the auspiciousness of the name *changing* and not the meaning of the new name, so it was just as likely for בנימין to turn into ראובן as חיים.

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember my source for this, but I recall learning that they used to completely change someone's name (not just his second name). Our adding a name is a modified version of that.

Answer (score 0):

The Gemara (Meseches Rosh Hashanah 16b) says that it is a change of a name which is a cure for an illness. It doesn't specify whether you change your name completely or you just add another name to yours, I would think that you should just add another name on, but don't take this as a psak ask your local Orthodox Rabbi.