# Prayer for changing name for transgender reasons?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, names, gender-identity

I am a transgender man and I would like to change my Hebrew and English names. Are there any specific prayers to go along with this, or any specific rules that I should be aware of? Thank you.

Comment: vvcl, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I think that your question is the same as [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47416/process-by-which-one-changes-their-name), which, so far, doesn't have a really comprehensive answer, unfortunately. The potentially distinguishing aspect here is the gender change, but I have no idea if that impacts what prayers or procedures would be necessary. In any case, "be aware of" is the right attitude toward what we can offer here. For an actual ruling on what to do, I recommend speaking with your rabbi.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Did you not VTC because the other question lacked an upvoted answer, or because the transgender aspect is distinctive?

Comment: @DoubleAA that (upvoted/comprehensive) plus the possibility the gender change is an essential part of this question that distinguishes it from the other.

Comment: The transgender aspect definitely distinguishes this question. I also think a very high degree of sensitivity was called for here which we did not necessarily deliver. He may have reasons not to ask his LOR.

Comment: @SAH Then he must find an OR even if not L that he can ask. We are not a substitute. (When you say "distinguish" do you mean from a proposed dupe? I don't see one. Is this not clearly a RFפ?)